# Set textbox value based on the combobox selected item

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set automatically the $MyTextBox value ($MyTextBox.text) based on the selected $MyComboBox

He is what I tried, but it doesn't work when I change the selected MyComboBox Item

```
$MyComboBox = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$MyComboBox.text = "My_ComboBox"
$MyComboBox.width = 204
$MyComboBox.height = 20
$MyComboBox.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(36, 275)
$MyComboBox.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'
$MyComboBox.ForeColor = "#9b9b9b"
$MyComboBox.Items.add("A")
$MyComboBox.Items.add("B")
$MyComboBox.Items.add("Other")
$MyComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0


$MyTextBox                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox

#What I tried but doesn't work
if( $MyComboBox.SelectedItem -eq "A") {$MyTextBox.text = "1" }
if( $MyComboBox.SelectedItem -eq "B") {$MyTextBox.text = "2" }

$InboxTextBox.multiline              = $false
$InboxTextBox.width                  = 100
$InboxTextBox.height                 = 20
$InboxTextBox.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(133,307)
$InboxTextBox.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
```

Do I need a trigger/function to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SelectedItem Property is an object, which you compare to a string object, and these objects are likley not to be the same.

Use

```
if( $MyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() -eq "A") {$MyTextBox.text = "1" }
```

or

```
if( $MyComboBox.SelectedIndex -eq 0) {$MyTextBox.text = "1" }
```

Update:

You should also add an Event Handler via `add_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
$MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged = 
{
   if( $MyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() -eq "A") {$MyTextBox.text = "1" }
   # other test cases...
}

$MyComboBox.add_SelectedIndexChanged($MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
```

Comment: thank you !  but it doesn't resolve my problem, when I selecte the "B" Item, the $MyTextBox.text doesn't get the value "2"